# Alternatives to SQL COUNT(*) practices?

Tags: database, postgresql, count, nosql

I was looking for improvements to PostgreSQL/InnoDB MVCC COUNT(*) problem when I found an article about implementing a [work around in PostgreSQL](http://blog.charcoalphile.com/2007/12/12/postgresql-count-workaround/). However, the author made a statement that caught my attention:

> MySQL zealots tend to point to
>   PostgreSQL’s slow count() as a
>   weakness, however, in the real world,
>   count() isn’t used very often, and if
>   it’s really needed, most good database
>   systems provide a framework for you to
>   build a workaround.

**Are there ways to skip using COUNT(*) in the way you design your applications?**

Is it true that most applications are designed so they don't need it? I use `COUNT()` on most of my pages since they all need pagination. What is this guy talking about? Is that why some sites only have a "next/previous" link?

Carrying this over into the NoSQL world, is this also something that has to be done there since you can't COUNT() records very easily?

Comment: that article is from 2007!! maybe postgres has improved his count algorithm...

Comment: In the real world relational integrity is often more important than fast counts. MySQL had to abandon its old dogma that that RI did not matter and add InnoDB. http://microjet.ath.cx/WebWiki/ResultPaginationWithPostgresql.html

Comment: FYI, this isn't really a question about PostgreSQL or MySQL. It's about how, or if it's possible, to design things so that record counts are not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think when the author said

```
however, in the real world, count() isn’t used very often
```

they specifically meant an *unqualified* `count(*)` isn't used very often, which is the specific case that MyISAM optimises.

My own experience backs this up- apart from some dubious Munin plugins, I can't think of the last time I did a `select count(*) from sometable`.

For example, anywhere I'm doing pagination, it's usually the output of some search. Which implies there will be a WHERE clause to limit the results anyway- so I might be doing something like `select count(*) from sometable where conditions` followed by `select ... from sometable limit n offset m`. Neither of which can use the direct how-many-rows-in-this-table shortcut.

Now it's true that if the conditions are purely index conditions, then some databases can merge together the output of covering indices to avoid looking at the table data too. Which certainly decreases the number of blocks looked at... if it works. It may be that, for example, this is only a win if the query can be satisfied with a single index- depends on the db implementation.

Still, this is by no means always the case- a lot of our tables have an `active` flag which isn't indexed, but often is filtered on, so would require a heap check anyway.

If you just need an idea of whether a table has data in it or not, Postgresql and many other systems do retain estimated statistics for each table: you can examine the `reltuples` and `relpages` columns in the catalogue for an *estimate* of how many rows the table has and how much space it is taking. Which is fine so long as ~6 significant figures is accurate enough for you, and some lag in the statistics being updated is tolerable. In my use case that I can remember (plotting the number of items in the collection) it would have been fine for me...

Trying to maintain an *accurate* row counter is tricky. The article you cited caches the row count in an auxiliary table, which introduces two problems:

- a race condition between SELECT and INSERT populating the auxiliary table (minor, you could seed this administratively)
- as soon as you add a row to the main table, you have an update lock on the row in the auxiliary table. now any other process trying to add to the main table has to wait.

The upshot is that concurrent transactions get serialised instead of being able to run in parallel, and you've lost the writers-dont-have-to-block-either benefits of MVCC- you should reasonably expect to be able to insert two independent rows into the same table at the same time.

MyISAM can cache the row count per table because it tacks on exclusive lock on the table when someone writes to it (iirc). InnoDB allows finer-grained locking-- but it doesn't try to cache the row count for the table. Of course if you don't care about concurrency and/or transactions, you can take shortcuts... but then you're moving away from Postgresql's main focus, where data integrity and ACID transactions are primary goals.

I hope this sheds some light. I must admit, I've never really felt the need for a faster "count(*)", so to some extent this is simply a "but it works for me" testament rather than a real answer.

Comment: Ah, I though the author was insinuating that he never used the `COUNT()` function at all. I too have never used a blanket `select count(*) from table` either. Though I always index all int columns that that is usually the only thing I ever pass to the WHERE portion of the COUNT() query.

Comment: Now, more importantly you just said that by using the authors [suggested method](http://blog.charcoalphile.com/2008/04/21/postgresql-ultra-simple-count-workaround/) you actually can introduce a race condition and "concurrent transactions get serialised instead of being able to run in parallel"? Can you explain that part a little more?

Comment: Basically, you can't have two transactions both modifying the same version of a row. If thread/transaction A does on update on some row, then any other transaction trying to update or delete that same row will block until A commits/aborts. By contrast, two threads inserting rows into the same table won't block each other (provided they are not about to violate a uniqueness constraint). But if inserting into the table fires a trigger that then updates a shared row in some other table- now the threads are trying to update that row, and whichever gets there first blocks the other.

Answer (score 0):

While you're asking more of an application design than database question really, there is more detail about how counting executes in PostgreSQL and the alternatives to doing so at [Slow Counting](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting).  If you must have a fast count of something, you can maintain one with a trigger, with examples in the references there.  That costs you a bit on the insert/update/delete side in return for speeding that up.  You have to know in advance what you will eventually want a count of for that to work though.